# What do CT numbers in SO-DIMM RAMs mean?

Tags: computers, ram

Here is a picture from the "crucial" website. I am trying to understand:

1. What is the difference between buying 2 separate 8GB sticks and one kit of two sticks.
2. What do the CT numbers mean and why are there two sets for each product?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are manufacturer's codes for items you can purchase.

1) Difference is you get one box with two 8GB sticks or one box with one 8GB stick. Sticks are all identical. Sometimes buying a pack of 2 is cheaper than two packs of one.

2) You might want to ask the manufacturer about this, as it does not have anything to do with electrical engineering.